# Credential Provider 'SetComboBoxSelectedValue' not called with appended field

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox, credential-providers

I am running SampleWrapExistingCredentialProvider from VistaCredentialProviderSamples and there is a function called 'SetComboBoxSelectedValue' in CSampleCredential.cpp file. This function is called when the user changes the selected item in the combobox and stores the selected item index However, when I append an item in the combobox at runtime using AppendFieldComboBoxItem function, and then if the appended item is selected, this function is not called. Because of this, I am not able to get the selected item index for the appended field.

I have tried to display a messagebox to see when this function is called. This function is called only if the one of the default combobox items are selected by user, and not called when the appended items are selected.

```
// Called when the user changes the selected item in the combobox. We'll check to see if 
// it's for us or the wrapped credential, and then handle or route it as appropriate.
HRESULT CSampleCredential::SetComboBoxSelectedValue(
DWORD dwFieldID,
DWORD dwSelectedItem
)
{
    HRESULT hr = E_UNEXPECTED;

// Make sure we have a wrapped credential.
if (_pWrappedCredential != NULL)
{
    // If this field belongs to the wrapped credential, hand it off.
    if (_IsFieldInWrappedCredential(dwFieldID))
    {
        hr = _pWrappedCredential->SetComboBoxSelectedValue(dwFieldID, dwSelectedItem);
    }
    // Otherwise determine if we need to handle it.
    else
    {
        FIELD_STATE_PAIR *pfsp = _LookupLocalFieldStatePair(dwFieldID);
        if ((pfsp != NULL) && (dwSelectedItem < ARRAYSIZE(s_rgDatabases)))
        {
            _dwComboIndex = dwSelectedItem;

            HWND hwndOwner = nullptr;
            if (_pCredProvCredentialEvents)
            {
                _pCredProvCredentialEvents->OnCreatingWindow(&hwndOwner);
            }
            TCHAR msg[100];
            StringCbPrintf(msg, 100, TEXT("%d"), _dwComboIndex);
            MessageBox(hwndOwner, msg, TEXT("Combobox selected ID"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

            hr = S_OK;
        }
        else
        {
            hr = E_INVALIDARG;
        }
    }
}

return hr;
}
```

I need to detect the combobox selected item index for the appended fields as well. Any help would be appreciated on how to detect the index of appended combobox item?

Answer (score 0):

New Combobox items will always be appended to the end of list.

It is your responsibility to track the order of appearance and you may maintain an internal "copy" of the list to track the changes.

Because you are working with `SampleWrapExistingCredentialProvider`, you can make a proxy class that will track calls from inside of wrapped provider to logon UI.

**Update**

I have just checked my provider's log.

I fill combo-box list inside of `GetSerialization` method.

After filling the list with several calls to `AppendFieldComboBoxItem` I manually call `SetFieldComboBoxSelectedItem` with third parameter  set to `0` to ensure that the first item is selected.

Then I set `pcpgsr` to `CPGSR_NO_CREDENTIAL_NOT_FINISHED` value.

When the control goes out of `GetSerialization` method Logon UI immediately calls me back with `SetComboBoxSelectedValue` and value `0`.

Comment: Lets say I maintain an internal copy of the list, but how to detect which item is selected at run time? Which function will be triggered when appended item is selected? because SetComboBoxSelectedValue is not being fired when appended item is selected. For others, it gets fired and I am able to detect the selected item index

Comment: I have two items by default in the list, others I append dynamically after API calls, at the time of initialization of credential provider. Now, my problem is, when the user clicks submit button after selecting an item from combobox, I am not able to get which item is selected by user

Comment: In my case my credential provider credential is called about combobox selection change.    
I'll check the log files...

Comment: Thanks, will really appreciate

Comment: Fixed up my answer with explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I am doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: But as you said 'When the control goes out of GetSerialization method Logon UI immediately calls me back with SetComboBoxSelectedValue and value 0.'. This way, I am also able to get the index and the selected item is updated. But, at this screen, if the user changes the selected item and chooses the item that was dynamically appended, this callback is not fired. However, this callback is fired if we select the default items that were statically included in the list, So I am not able to detect the index when selected by user. I hope you get my point?

Comment: In my scenario all of my items in the list is added dynamically. Initially my CP's Combo list is empty and the whole Combo is hidden.

Comment: Ok.. I have achieved my objective by doing a workaround: I have used the deletion approach instead of append approach. I amincluding all the items in the list statically at the time of initialization, then at run time, I delete the items dynamically which I don't require for a user. In this case, if a user requires all items, I don't delete any item and able to get the index of all items